# Running Oozie Workflow gives Error: E0732

Tags: oozie

I am running a oozie workflow on Oozie 3.3.2 that gives following error
`Error: E0732 : E0732: Fork <fork>/Join[join1]`  not in pair (join should have been [join2])

Now the same workflow runs fine on Oozie 2.3.2
Is this something version specific or this error is thrown in some other case
please help

Answer (score 0):

Can you validate your workflow

```
oozie validate workflow.xml
```

And then see if some issue is there this suggests something wrong with xml

Comment: Shows Valid workflow-app. But it worked only after changing fork job <ok to ="join2"/> which was <ok to ="join1"/> initially

Comment: The right solution to make your logically correct workflow work is to disable forkjoin validation by adding oozie.wf.validate.ForkJoin=false to job.properties file

Comment: @user3410113 , we have the property already set to false but we still get this error. The actual execution of the job is correct but the workflow shows as failed!